# Activerecord mass assignment to virtual attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm posting the following datas:

```
{"commit"=>"Create", "conversation"=>{... , "watchers_ids"=>["2", "3", "4", "5", ...]}}
```

To the following action

```
def create
  @conversation = @current_project.conversations.new(params[:conversation]) 
  ...
end
```

And the following class

```
class Conversation < RoleRecord
  include Watchable
end
```

With this module

```
module Watchable
  def self.included(model)
    model.attr_accessible :watchers_ids
  end

  def watchers_ids=(ids)
    add_watchers( ids )
  end

  def watchers_ids
    ...
  end


  ...
end
```

However, the mass assignment don't work with the virtual attribute. Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure `watchers_ids=` isn't being called? Try logging a message from that method.

Answer (score 0):

There's code that's missing there...

If you have a `has_and_belongs_to_many :watchers` you should be able to assign `watcher_ids` without having to do this custom module stuff.

Then if you can't do that then that attribute is protected by some `attr_protected` or, more likely, `attr_accessible` call in your model. You can set it manually:

```
@conversation.watcher_ids = params[:conversation][:watcher_ids]
```